# How to swap between two stylesheets with one button in jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery

I have one button to change between a "light theme" and "dark theme", but I've only managed to make it change once, and not back again. I would really appreciate any help!

```
<link id="sheet" href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

/

```
$(".themebutton").click(function() {
if($('a[href="main.css"]'))
{
  $("#sheet").attr('href','dark.css');
}
else {
  $("#sheet").attr('href','main.css');
}
});
```

Also is there a way to stop the "flickering" that happens when the stylesheet loads?

Comment: I add an snippet in my answer to see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to make this is to make a classname to the `html` tag. Imagine this two classes:

```
 .theme1 { 
    background:red;
 }
 .theme1 h1 {
     color: blue;
 }
 .theme2 {
    background: green;
 }
 .theme2 h1 {
     color: orange;
 }
```

You can switch without flickering and without new requests to server like this:

```
 $('.change-theme-1').on('click', function() {
      $('html').addClass('theme1');
 }
```

Here you are a snippet to see it working.

```js
$('.change-theme').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html').addClass('theme'+$(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

```css
.theme1 { 
  background:red;
}
.theme1 h1 {
  color: blue;
}
.theme2 {
  background: green;
}
.theme2 h1 {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
  <body>
    <h1>That's a header</h1>
    <button class="change-theme" rel="1">Theme 1</button><br>
    <button class="change-theme" rel="2">Theme 2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! This is a really cool solution, but I was hoping to save myself the trouble of adding a new class to everything and making the changes, especially since I already have the stylesheet ready.. I also need it work with only one button, which was my main issue. Still, your reply will come in handy on future projects!

Comment: That's the correct way. Change stylesheets in hot will cause flickering, lag on load, new requests to server and mind-breaking. If you use SASS or LESS you can wrap all codes with the classname and you don't need to add the class to all. Good luck!